# Proving generators of $D_{2n}$ are distinct.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I'm sorry if this is such silly question, but I can't seem to prove how the presentation of $D_{2n}$ keeps $r \neq s$ for $n = 2$. We have
$$
\langle r,s \mid r^2 = s^2 = e, sr^{-1} = rs \rangle
$$

If they're equal, then $r = r^{-1} = s$, so
$$
rs = sr^{-1} = e.
$$
I can't find a contradiction; where am I going wrong? If this is the Klein four group, I must not be getting something simple since it looks like can also generate $\langle r \rangle$.

Comment: That just means that the cyclic group of order 2 is a quotient of $D_4$. $D_4$ is the most general group satisfying the conditions, and any group that satisfies the conditions is a quotient thereof. (The relations would also be satisfied if $r=s=e$, but you can't conclude from that they are all trivial).

Comment: So, when we speak of the dihedral group $D_{4}$, we must assume the distinctness of the generators. Thus, when Dummit and Foote give this presentation, a non-trivial interpretation must be assumed since the presentation can't rule out trivial ones? Thanks by the way.

Comment: It's not that you "mut assume distinctness". It's that you do not assume any equality that you cannot derive from the relations given. $r=s$ is not something you derive from the relations, so you cannot assume it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess,  the point is that there's a group,  the Klein four group,  in which $r\neq s$, and that group satisfies all the relations.

In a real sense,  you quotient $F_2$, the free group on $2$ generators,  by the smallest normal subgroup containing the relators.

That means you take the largest group possible.   (And it's easy to show that the group has order at most four,  using the anti-commutativity relation:   $aba=b^{-1}$.)

So the group has order four.   And is not cyclic (no element of order four).